# Is there a simple way to print multiple images on the same page in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, images, printing, photos

I'm looking for a simple way to print multiple images on the same page. The default image printing function in Windows lets me select how many images I want on each page. How do I do this on the Mac?

When I select multiple images in the Finder and then File / Print, the Preview app opens and prints just the first selected image. If I try the same one more time, nothing gets printed!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Open all images you want to print in Preview at the same time (select all, then open). They will be opened in the same window, with a sidebar (similar to a multi-plage PDF).

How to proceed depends on your OS X version.

### Printing on Mac OS X Lion and later

Select *File » Print* and then change *Layout » Pages per Sheet*.

[image: Print dialog screenshot]

### Printing on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and earlier

Select the images you want to print in the sidebar.

[image: Image selection in sidebar screenshot]

Then select *File » Print Selected Images…*. There you can configure to print multiple images per page.

[image: Print dialog screenshot]